# AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'collide' Pygame

Tags: python, oop, pygame, attributeerror, group

I'm creating a basic simulation in pygame and my object (an amoeba represented by a green square on the screen) has two methods. My update method is running fine, but the collide method is giving my an attribute error. By the way, since I have added many amoebae to the screen, I apply the methods to my amoebas group.

```
import pygame
import random
import time

from pygame.locals import (
    QUIT
)

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])

amoebas = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Amoeba(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, maturingSpeed, x, y):
        super(Amoeba, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((10,10))
        self.surf.fill((0, maturingSpeed, 0))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                x,
                y,
            )
        )
        self.speed = 2
        self.age = 1
        self.maturingSpeed = maturingSpeed    

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.left <= 0:
            direction = 1
        elif self.rect.right >= SCREEN_WIDTH:
            direction = 2
        elif self.rect.top <= 0:
            direction = 3
        elif self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            direction = 4
        else:
            direction = random.randint(1, 4)
            
        if direction == 1:
            self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)
        elif direction == 2:
            self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        elif direction == 3:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)
        elif direction == 4:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed)

    def collide(self):  
        posList = [(amoeba.rect.left, amoeba.rect.top) for amoeba in list]
        length = len(posList)
        print(posList)
        print(length)
        for i in range(length):
          y = posList[i]
          for h in range(length):
              if posList[h] == y and h != i:
                  locationX = posList[i][0]
                  locationY = posList[i][1]
                  new_amoeba = Amoeba(150, locationX, locationY)
                  amoebas.add(new_amoeba)
                  all_sprites.add(new_amoeba)
              else:
                  pass

screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

for i in range(100):
        new_amoeba = Amoeba(150, random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH), random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
        amoebas.add(new_amoeba)
        all_sprites.add(new_amoeba)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.000001)
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            break
    
    amoebas.update()
    amoebas.collide()

    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)
        
    pygame.display.flip()
    

pygame.quit()
```

I'm very new to OOP and this is my first complex program written in it, so any advice is welcome!
Also, I know my question is pretty much identical to this one: [Python is throwing AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'blitme'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661604/python-is-throwing-attributeerror-group-object-has-no-attribute-blitme)  but unfortuantely I could not understand the answer so any help with that would also be welcome.

Comment: Could you share the error message?

Comment: It's the same as the title: AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'collide'

Comment: `amoebas` is a Group of course it has no `collide` method

Comment: I'm also getting an error with my posList used to identify the positions of the amoebae. It's this: TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The latter delegates to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) — you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group. [...]

The former uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects — you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

Therefore you can call `amoebas.update()` and `amoebas.draw(screen)`, but you can't call `amoebas.collide()`.

You must call the `collide` methods in a loop:

```py
for amoeba in amoebas;
    amoeba.collide()
```